# problem code=exited, status=203/EXEC) when systemctl start odoo15

Tags: python-3.x

I installed  odoo 15 in vps and when I try start odoo15 by run

`systemctl start odoo15` 
after that run :

`systemctl status odoo15`

I installed odoo 15 in vps and when I try start odoo15 by run

`systemctl start odoo15` 
after that run

`systemctl status odoo15`

`● odoo15.service - Odoo15
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odoo15.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-01-05 12:25:15 UTC; 8s ago
Process: 19453 ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo15-venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo15/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 19453 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 05 12:25:15 vps103.com\ systemd[1]:\ Started\ Odoo15.
Jan\ 05\ 12:25:15\ vps103.com\ systemd[1]:\ odoo15.service:\ main\ proces...C
Jan\ 05\ 12:25:15\ vps103.com\ systemd[1]:\ Unit\ odoo15.service\ entered....
Jan\ 05\ 12:25:15\ vps103.com systemd[1]: odoo15.service failed.
`
Can any one help me, please?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

solution：close SELinux

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

change: SELINUX=disabled and reboot

check SELinux status: getenforce